# Weird boost unordered_map error

Tags: c++, boost

I have already 3-4 unordered_maps with boost and all work fine.
Now I wanted to do another one but Im getting wrong output from the map.

Struct:

```
struct sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE
{
    TBLIDX  tblidx;
    BYTE    bySlot;
    BYTE    byType;
    HOBJECT hItem;
};
```

Functions:

```
sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE*    GetQuickSlotSkillDataFromList(BYTE SlotIndex);
void                    AddQuickSlotSkillDataToMyList(BYTE SlotIndex, sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE* skilldata);
boost::unordered_map<BYTE, sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE*> p_QuickSlotSkillData;
```

asQuickSlotData

```
BEGIN_PROTOCOL(GU_QUICK_SLOT_INFO)  
    BYTE                byQuickSlotCount;
    sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE asQuickSlotData[10];
END_PROTOCOL()
```

Add to map:

```
res->asQuickSlotData[slotID].tblidx = pSkillData->tblidx;
res->asQuickSlotData[slotID].bySlot = i;
res->asQuickSlotData[slotID].byType = (pSkillData->bySkill_Class==NTL_SKILL_CLASS_HTB?QUICK_SLOT_TYPE_HTB_SKILL:QUICK_SLOT_TYPE_SKILL);
res->asQuickSlotData[slotID].hItem = 0;

pPlayer->AddQuickSlotSkillDataToMyList(slotID, res->asQuickSlotData);
```

The AddQuickSlotSkillDataToMyList function:

```
void PlayerInfos::AddQuickSlotSkillDataToMyList(BYTE SlotIndex, sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE* skilldata)
{
    printf("ADD DATA %d %d %d %d %d \n", SlotIndex,  skilldata->bySlot, skilldata->byType, skilldata->hItem, skilldata->tblidx);
    p_QuickSlotSkillData.insert(make_pair(SlotIndex, skilldata));
}
```

Now the get data function:

```
sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE* PlayerInfos::GetQuickSlotSkillDataFromList(BYTE SlotIndex)
{
    itertype(p_QuickSlotSkillData) it = p_QuickSlotSkillData.find(SlotIndex);

    if (p_QuickSlotSkillData.end() == it){
        printf("error \n");
        return 0;
    }

    sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE* quickslot = it->second;
    if (quickslot == NULL) {
        printf(error 2 \n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("FOUND DATA %d %d %d %d %d \n", SlotIndex,  quickslot->bySlot, quickslot->byType, quickslot->hItem, quickslot->tblidx);

    return quickslot;

}
```

Image to see the printf:
http://s7.directupload.net/images/140924/we78r9kq.jpg

Now as you see it adds the correct data into the map but the output is trash.

Whats wrong? I dont understand. Im sitting already 3 hours at this ..

Got a solution:

```
void PlayerInfos::AddQuickSlotSkillDataToMyList(BYTE SlotIndex, sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE* skilldata)
{
    printf("ADD DATA %d %d %d %d %d \n", SlotIndex,  skilldata->bySlot, skilldata->byType, skilldata->hItem, skilldata->tblidx);

        sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE* rofl = new sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE;
        rofl->bySlot = skilldata->bySlot;
        rofl->byType = skilldata->byType;
        rofl->hItem = skilldata->hItem;
        rofl->tblidx = skilldata->tblidx;

    p_QuickSlotSkillData.insert(make_pair(SlotIndex, rofl));

    //  delete rofl;
}
```

Comment: "sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE* quickslot = it->second;" Change this line -> sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE* quickslot = &it->second;

Comment: Thanks. Tryed but getting the error "cannot convert from 'sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE **' to 'sQUICK_SLOT_PROFILE *'"

Comment: `pPlayer->AddQuickSlotSkillDataToMyList(slotID, &res->asQuickSlotData[slotID]);` maybe?

Comment: Then at the "add data printf" everything is zero. And if I do &res->asQuickSlotData[i] then the output is trash too

Comment: How is `asQuickSlotData` defined? You're not really posting enough code for anyone to know for sure what's going on.

Comment: I'm going to make a guess - the pointers you're adding to the unordered_map are to local variables, which are invalid after the function doing the adding returns.

Comment: Looks like youre right, mark. I got a solution now.